# Progam can't see file but it exist. FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, copy-paste, filenotfoundexception

So, I'm writing FTP server-client but the code can't read any file. I mean. I have a file at Downloads. Let's say /Downloads/supplement2.pdf but I get a FileNotFoundException. Even though the file is there and I can see it. I even made a test folder and set it's privilages to 777. Still, nothing.

Is there a way to set what netbeans does as superuser or something? I mean. I just want to copy and paste something but can't. Here's the copy and paste code. If you see anything wrong with it please share.

```
 public static void copyFile(File in, File out)
        throws IOException
    {
        FileChannel inChannel = new
            FileInputStream(in).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = new
            FileOutputStream(out).getChannel();
        try {
            inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(),
                    outChannel);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if (inChannel != null) inChannel.close();
            if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you're not in a chroot, are you?

Comment: Out of interest, are you writing this as a programming exercise? (... because otherwise there are numerous Java FTP library implementations you could use).

Comment: Just for clarification - do you get the FNFE for the input file, the target folder or the target file?

Comment: SO is eating comments - the comment that Kevin_Jim replied to contained the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486494/filenotfoundexception-thrown-when-the-file-does-exists

Comment: @Kevin - for sure, at least it's a similar problem and - I assume you used Search before asking ;-) - Just kidding - the other problem was caused by missing user access rights for the application.

Answer (score 2):

Are you specifying the right path to the file?

You can try specifying the full path or placing a file in the same directory as the code.

Comment: What I want to do is copy-paste the file from/to the local Netbeans folder and yes the folder is absolutely right. I thinks the problem is about the restrictions from java that I have to somewhat to lift or something.

Comment: Java is normally started with the same rights as you have. 
If it was a file restrictions problem, you would probably get something like "FileNotFound exception (Access Denied)"

Answer (score 1):

Try just creating a new file  with an unusual name, writing something to it and then finding the file in your file system.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted and called your code with

```
copyFile(new File("C:/TEMP/Folder1/test.txt"), 
         new File("C:/TEMP/Folder2/test.txt"));
```

while only file in folder 1 existed and - yes, it worked. A complete stack trace could be helpful. Is any folder or document in the source or target path a mount or a link?